# Why this trivally incorrect lemma can be proved using sos?

Tags: isabelle

I'm new to Isabelle and have encountered a problem that I'm struggling with. I have the following lemma:

```
imports Main HOL.HOL HOL.Real "HOL-Library.Sum_of_Squares"

lemma 
  fixes r :: real
  assumes "r = 8/7" 
  shows "r = 2"
proof-
  show "r = 2" using assms by sos 
qed
```

I would like to understand why Isabelle accepts this proof despite the contradiction. Is it something related to the `sos` method, or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about the way proofs work in Isabelle?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you in advance for your help.

The Isabelle theorem prover accepts this proof and outputs "No subgoals!" However, I'm puzzled, as the lemma is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Could you also provide the `imports` you are using? (The method `sos` (sum of squares?) is not defined in HOL/Main. So, Isabelle should throw an error, unless you have imported it.)

Comment: @BenKeks Thank you. The method `sos` is defined in "HOL-Library.Sum_of_Squares" (It is recently introduced, see [NEWS](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/NEWS.html)). the used `imports` is   `Main HOL.HOL HOL.Real "HOL-Library.Sum_of_Squares"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly a user interface problem. The Isabelle/jEdit 2022 window for this proof should look like this:

[image: Isabelle editor window with by sos highlighted in thistle]

Notice that the `by sos` is still highlighted in thistle. This is Isabelle/jEdit's way of communicating that the **proof method has not terminated yet**. (But it also has not given up yet. Giving up would be highlighted in pink.)

Compare the line to the trivial `by rule` proof that I've added in the line above. This is what checked proof steps look like.

Thus, `by sos` has not proven the bogus claim. (Phew!)

### Then what's with the “No subgoals”?

But why is Isabelle then claiming `No subgoals` in the proof state?! The answer is that Isabelle tries to check the theory in a parallelized manner. A proof method that takes long should not block the other proof-checking threads. So, other threads continue from that line with the hypothesis that, should `by sos` terminate, there would be no remaining subgoals and they could use the proven lemma.

The main effect of this is that one can open, check, and edit theories much faster than one could if there were no parallelization. But it also means that following proof steps could indeed complete even though the theory is broken.

As long as there are any highlighted proof steps, everything below could be false, even though individual proof steps are sound.